# Get functionname from the functionpointer?

Tags: delphi, function-pointers, delphi-2007

I have a pointer to functions like this.

```
TTestEvent = function(): Boolean;

procedure ExecuteTest(aTest: TTestEvent; aType: String);
begin
  if aTest then
    NotifyLog(aType + ' success')
  else
    TestError(aType + ' failed');
end;

// Call the test
procedure TestAll;
begin
  ExecuteTest(LoadParcels, 'LoadParcel');
end;
```

But it would be even nicer to extract the name of the function from the functionpointer aTest.

So instead of

```
aType + ' success'
```

I want something like

```
ExtractName(aTest) + ' success'
```

Can this be done in Delphi 2007 ?

Comment: Looks like a good place to use attribute.

Comment: @Pol: Only valid for recent Delphi versions implementing advanced Rtti capabilities.

Comment: I just want something simple. So the answer It is not possible unless I use JCLDebug or MadExcept is fine for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this with built-in features. In order to get a function name from an address you need to know the map of the executable. This is not part of an executable unless you take steps to add it.

Debugging tools like JclDebug and madExcept offer the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

If you use some of our Open Source classes, you'll be able to find the name of any symbol.

You'll have to create a `.map` file when building your executable, by setting "Detailed map" in your projects option.

You can then deliver the `.map` with the `.exe`, or compress the `.map` into our proprietary `.mab` format, which can be appended to the `.exe`. The `.mab` format is just a lot more efficient than `.zip`  or other for this task: it is about 10 times smaller than the original `.map` file (that is, much smaller than JCLDebug or MaxExpect offers, and very much smaller than using the standard "Remote debugging symbol" embedding project option).

Then you can use the `TSynMapFile` class to retrieve debugging information from the `.map` file, or the information embedded into the `.exe`:

```
function ExtractName(aSymbolAddress: pointer): string;
var i: integer;
begin
  with TSynMapFile.Create do // no name supplied -> will read from .exe
  try
    i := FindSymbol(aSymbolAddress);
    if i>=0 then
      result := Symbols[i].Name else
      result := '';
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

It will work for function names, but also any other symbols, like methods or global variables.

See [this blog article](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/04/14/Enhanced-logging-in-SynCommons) about the class. And note that even if it is used by our mORMot framework, or its logging features, you just do not need to use the whole framework (just [`SynCommons.pas`](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCommons.pas) and [`SynLZ.pas`](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynLZ.pas) units). See the [Map2Mab.dpr](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SQLite3/Samples/11+-+Exception+logging/Map2Mab.dpr) program in "SQLite3\Samples\11 - Exception logging" sub folder to embed .map file content into an .exe.

Comment: +1 Nice solution! The .map/.mab file may be tampered. How can security concern be adressed? Should I post a new question?

Comment: @menjaraz If you embed/append the .mab content to the .exe (as I propose in the solution), it won't be easily tampered, and would simplify deployment (just one .exe). And you'll be able to add some nice features to your application, as exception logging with stack trace (including source code line numbers).

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Why would tampering be hard? And I don't mean this critically because I believe that any time a map is appended to an exe it is simple for a hacker to read it. We personally use madExcept but do not distribute the .mad file. Out users e-mail bug reports with addresses from which we can then produce meaningful stack traces since we do have the .mad files for all released versions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You could easily add some encryption to our .mab content (since all source code is provided), for privacy. And tampering an .exe binary content will be more difficult than changing a .map text file. For stack trace in hexa, it is the default for our TSynLog, if no .map/.mab is available: in this case, you can retrieve directly the symbol from our [log viewer tool](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/08/20/Enhanced-Log-viewer), from the ".map" button. But inside a log file, this is less attractive.

Answer (score 0):

You may implement a registration mechanism based on a `Dictionary` with

- the function pointer as a `Key` and
- the function name as a `Value`.

`ExtractName` would be a method of the dictionary.

Don't forget to make it thread safe if need be.